# How to append rails checkbox tag with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to append the value from the option fields to the checkboxes fields in Rails by using javascript.

So in my javascript code I did this:

```
$("#regions option").each(function(){
  $("#region-checkboxes").append('<li><%= check_box_tag "region_id", ' + $(this).val() + ' %></li>');
});
```

But I got a list of empty result:

[image]

And below is screenshot from the view source of this empty list:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to mix the server side code (rails) with the client side code (javascript/jquery).

Instead you would want it to look something like this:

```
$("#regions option").each(function(){
  $("#region-checkboxes").append('<li><input id="region_id" name="region_id" type="checkbox" value="' + $(this).val() + '" /></li>');
});
```